# Использование Pandas DataFrame Pivot для подсчета и отображения статистики

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pivot

Как с помощью DataFrame Pivot, подсчитать статистику выпадания шаров лотореи с разбивкой по категориям шаров для каждой игры, и вывести результат в виде pivot table (x=draw_id, y=category, result = count())? Категория для каждого шара задана в массиве bc в столбце category

Пример подсчетат статистики по категориям для первой игры

```
1) Шары: 9;11;17;29;30;33;36 соотвествующие им категории: 2;5;8;4;2;6;11 
2) Результат статистики по категориям = {2:2, 5:1, 8:1, 4:1, 6:1, 11:1}
```

Ожидаемый результат. Пример статистики для первых трех игр

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исходный код

```
import pandas as pd 
import argparse as ap
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations
from prettytable import PrettyTable
from collections import Counter
import json
from random import randint
from itertools import chain
import operator
from functools import reduce

def ArgParser():
    parser = ap.ArgumentParser(description='Description of your program')
    parser.add_argument('-d','--draws', help='Test result', required=True)
    args = vars(parser.parse_args())
    return args

def main():

    args = ArgParser()
    draws = pd.read_csv(args['draws'], sep=';',header=0, index_col='draw_id')

    bc = (draws.stack().value_counts()).to_frame(name='count')
    bc['category'] = np.arange(len(bc)) // 3


    print(bc)


    print('The End')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

1) Результат работы скрипта

```
    count  category
32     28         0
6      27         0
27     26         0
1      25         1
22     24         1
13     24         1
4      23         2
30     23         2
9      23         2
23     23         3
12     23         3
15     23         3
29     22         4
8      22         4
28     21         4
16     21         5
25     21         5
11     21         5
7      20         6
18     20         6
33     20         6
19     19         7
21     19         7
24     19         7
26     19         8
17     18         8
35     18         8
5      18         9
14     17         9
31     16         9
3      16        10
2      15        10
10     14        10
36     12        11
34     11        11
20     10        11
```

Исходные данные.

```
draw_id;ball1;ball2;ball3;ball4;ball5;ball6;ball7
1;9;11;17;29;30;33;36
2;5;6;9;11;15;33;28
3;4;5;10;14;20;30;8
4;4;21;22;25;26;36;6
5;1;11;13;17;24;29;36
6;2;17;22;24;27;30;1
7;4;15;26;28;29;35;34
8;12;22;24;26;31;33;2
9;6;9;16;24;33;34;17
10;3;8;12;19;27;31;1
11;4;5;7;9;14;20;25
12;9;20;32;33;35;36;22
13;16;19;23;25;29;32;12
14;6;10;11;17;33;35;15
15;1;5;16;19;22;28;33
16;3;6;7;8;16;29;12
17;1;3;10;19;24;32;23
18;9;25;27;29;33;35;22
19;7;13;17;18;21;34;6
20;7;14;18;20;27;33;28
21;1;3;5;8;22;23;25
22;4;5;13;19;28;34;11
23;3;24;26;32;35;36;14
24;2;7;18;22;30;32;4
25;5;22;28;30;31;33;3
26;1;4;6;28;31;32;13
27;7;10;15;18;23;30;8
28;6;10;12;16;18;19;4
29;9;12;16;21;23;27;3
30;6;15;18;19;25;29;2
31;4;7;22;28;29;30;15
32;3;7;14;18;33;35;29
33;4;14;21;23;28;29;30
34;2;5;9;21;26;27;20
35;1;3;9;11;13;17;27
36;11;13;15;28;32;35;18
37;3;11;16;21;28;35;15
38;1;2;12;13;14;15;6
39;5;10;13;16;18;21;20
40;1;4;18;23;32;36;7
41;6;9;13;17;18;35;23
42;11;13;19;23;24;27;12
43;2;3;8;14;32;35;25
44;1;5;12;14;21;25;9
45;2;4;15;25;28;31;9
46;19;21;23;26;30;35;2
47;11;16;22;23;24;30;8
48;8;9;11;27;30;35;32
49;1;15;22;26;31;32;25
50;3;5;8;12;16;21;7
51;7;8;13;21;22;32;30
52;1;4;8;14;27;30;12
53;2;16;20;22;27;30;21
54;1;5;16;25;27;36;22
55;4;26;28;30;32;33;6
56;5;10;13;18;24;27;29
57;1;4;5;8;22;25;28
58;3;11;24;27;29;34;17
59;1;2;6;9;14;23;32
60;5;10;12;15;24;33;22
61;5;12;15;23;24;32;18
62;2;5;11;13;25;28;10
63;8;13;18;19;27;31;12
64;7;9;11;23;32;34;22
65;2;4;7;15;27;30;26
66;4;12;15;16;17;19;11
67;6;7;9;12;17;19;27
68;12;17;25;27;32;33;36
69;6;19;20;26;27;35;21
70;6;15;21;32;34;35;1
71;4;7;9;10;14;23;26
72;6;21;26;30;31;32;28
73;3;8;13;22;29;31;12
74;6;8;13;15;27;34;5
75;8;13;24;29;31;33;6
76;6;14;17;23;26;32;21
77;4;9;15;16;23;32;13
78;1;8;13;23;27;33;24
79;1;13;16;26;29;32;6
80;9;12;16;22;24;35;32
81;8;9;18;19;23;28;20
82;1;6;7;20;28;29;32
83;8;17;22;25;26;31;11
84;3;11;18;24;26;29;1
85;10;11;13;21;27;30;6
86;2;13;23;25;30;35;29
87;14;16;17;25;29;30;4
88;7;8;12;22;25;31;16
89;16;23;24;27;32;33;19
90;6;16;18;25;27;28;7
91;13;15;17;19;24;32;6
92;1;12;15;19;27;34;36
93;3;6;7;9;18;33;31
94;6;11;12;14;21;29;23
95;8;11;14;15;29;36;22
96;1;9;14;25;30;32;26
97;4;10;25;31;35;36;17
98;9;16;27;32;35;36;23
99;10;21;28;29;31;34;17
100;1;12;13;24;26;33;22
101;2;4;15;18;19;30;8
102;4;7;10;19;30;33;34
103;1;11;15;18;28;31;26
```

Comment: Можете привести в вопросе пример результирующей `"pivot table"` (несколько строк и столбцов)? Формулировка `вывести результат в виде pivot table (x=draw_id, y=category, result = count())` без примера - непонятная.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
bc = (draws.stack().value_counts()).to_frame(name='count')
bc['category'] = np.arange(len(bc)) // 3

res = (draws.stack()
            .map(bc['category'])
            .reset_index(name='category')
            .pivot_table(index='draw_id', columns='category', 
                         aggfunc='size', fill_value=0))
```

результат:

```
In [148]: res
Out[148]:
category  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11
draw_id
1          0   0   2   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   1
2          1   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0
3          0   0   2   0   1   0   0   0   0   2   1   1
4          1   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   1
5          0   2   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1
6          1   2   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0
7          0   0   1   1   2   0   0   0   2   0   0   1
8          0   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0
9          1   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   1
10         1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   0
...       ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
94         1   0   0   2   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0
95         0   1   0   1   2   1   0   0   0   1   0   1
96         1   1   2   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0
97         0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   2   1   1   1
98         2   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1
99         0   0   0   0   2   0   0   1   1   1   1   1
100        0   3   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0
101        0   0   2   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   0
102        0   0   2   0   0   0   2   1   0   0   1   1
103        0   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0

[103 rows x 12 columns]
```